# Creating a batch file or something else to start services such as Databases?

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

I am using windows 7-64 bit and SQL Server database. I wanted to create a batch file/any which I can simply click to start all its services. I want to avoid the drudgery of clicking and manually starting each once of them. But, I don't want them to be run automatically on start up.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard NET command to start each service in your batch file. See ["How do I start/stop a Windows Service from the command line?"](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#StartStopFromCommandLine) in the Windows Services FAQ for the details.

Comment: How do I do it using a batch file ?

Comment: Add a sequence of NET commands to a new batch file. For example, to start two services named "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS" and "SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS", your batch file would contain two lines: `NET START "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"`   and   `NET START "SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS"`